# Metadata for service provider. Using OpenSAML

Tags: java, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml, service-provider

I'm using the opensaml for our application that acts as Service Provider. 
So far, I have been manually creating the SP Metadata.
Is there example in Java to show how to programatically generate Service
Provider Metadata ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EntityDescriptor is the base of metadata, so thats what you start with, just add in the elements you whant by adding java object with usually the same name. Then you marshall the entitydescriptor and print xml.

I talk you through it on [this blog page](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2012/02/generating-metadata-with-opensaml.html).

In my book, [A Guide to OpenSAML](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html), I have a lot of information and examples on OpenSAML.

EDIT [New edition of the book](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html) is out, covering OpenSAML V3

Comment: How can i insert <X509Certificate> into <KeyDescriptor> tag?

Comment: hm.. i think question is not correct. i'm trying to rephrase. how get correct credential from keystore?  and then use them into keyInfo. because now it looks like <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing"/> without X509Certificate

Comment: Here is some on how to get credentials. To put it in a keyinfo I thing you use something called keyinfofactory, but I havn't tried this http://mylifewithjava.blogspot.no/2011/03/getting-credentials-in-opensaml.html

Comment: Your blog post uses SAMLUtil, that doesn't seem to be part of OpenSAML, what is it?

Comment: This is just my own helper methods. I have collected the relevant ones here http://blog.samlsecurity.com/2011/04/convenience-methods-for-opensaml.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Stefan Rasmusson's blog you can checkout Vladimir Shafer's sample application showing use of spring-security-saml2 integration with spring application has pre-written code for automated metadata generation and has clean GUI for testing it also.

Link to spring-security-saml sample application [Github Repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/tree/master/sample)
Link to [MetadataGenerator Class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/metadata/MetadataGenerator.java)